# Angular 1.4.7 ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue with `ng-repeat` where is throwing an injection error. I'm not an advance angular developer, a novice maybe. But I know this was working at one point and then poof. Gone!

What did I do different? I changed my localhost path to angular to a CDN instead. I tested it in the template I copied this work from originally and it works there. But not in my site.

My HTML:

```
<div id="cbp-vm" class="activegrid">
      <ul id="product" class="nav-pills nav-stacked rectangle-list" ng-controller="dataImagesWork">
          <li class="col-md-4 my-gallery-animation-home3" ng-repeat="product in images_work | filter:myFilter">
              <img ng-src="../img/projects/{{product.src}}" alt="{{product.name}}" /><br />
              <label class="title" href=""> {{product.name}} </label>
              <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right" href="{{product.link}}" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">View</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
app.controller("dataImagesWork", function ($scope) {
$scope.images_work = [
      {
          "name": 'PA Liquor Control Board',
          "src": "Liquor-Control-Board340.png",
          "link": "http://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StoreCatalogDisplay?storeId=10051&catalogId=10051&langId=-1"
      },
      {
          "name": 'PA Provider Self Service',
          "src": "Provider-Services-of-PA340.png",
          "link": 'https://www.pelican.state.pa.us/provider/default.aspx?TYPE=33554433&REALMOID=06-ccc2a1cb-0683-440f-bfa6-cad042af12ba&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=-SM-ZW9pIAMntaN%2bR%2fAG5q4UUzXVDz%2bKoMG2pXXJCs1re8tkRKCZKtgqJypoW9Af5ilo&TARGET=-SM-https%3a%2f%2fwww%2epelican%2estate%2epa%2eus%2fprovider%2fui%2fhome%2easpx#'
      },
      {
          "name": 'Job Gateway',
          "src": "JobGateway340.png",
          "link": 'https://www.jobgateway.pa.gov/jponline/Admin/Common/Portal.aspx?w@cIRFbHc_kyIfEUDPqYpUspb3u_@dnsvVOXen8isTEcdYg4grazpGUr2rtw4QN@odjSSGi8RwBm4_nraX__ITaRZJT8HYWbn3TgGPFcA0A-6xUQEkG_y@pHEMFmjDEEwSppJHEDfIGrVG6yQ4mCf4aazFA4QpEE'
      },
      {
          "name": 'Keystone Canine Rescue',
          "src": "KeystoneCanineRescue340.png",
          "link": 'http://www.keystonecaninerescue.org/'
      }];
 });
```

Here is the error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider%20%3C-%20n%20%3C-NaNataImagesWork
> at Error (native)
> at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js:6:416
> at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js:40:409
> at Object.d [as get] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js:38:394)
> at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js:40:483
> at d (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js:38:394)
> at Object.e [as invoke] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js:39:161)
> at P.instance (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js:80:207)
> at K (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js:61:190)
> at g (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js:54:410)

Any help would be appreciated

Here is a [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/aNmwxv) if it helps

Comment: It gives you all the information what is wrong: "Module 'uiGmapgoogle-maps' is not available!". Just fix it by adding/removing necessary modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loading `uiGmapgoogle-maps` module files,
Removing uiGmapgoogle-maps from your angular module dependencies will solve this issue.

```
var app = angular.module('angula', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial']);
```

In addition, you didn't attach the filter file so you will need to remove the filter from your ngRepeat.

```
<li class="col-md-4 my-gallery-animation-home3" ng-repeat="product in images_work">
```

See working sample at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKLdyP?editors=1011

Comment: Weird. In the codepen it clearly works. But after replacing the code in my app it still shows the same error. Could there be another dependency you can think of off the top of your head? Als removing the google map will stop the angular google map from working, but I was thinking about replacing that for another one anyway, so no big whoop on that one.

Comment: @LOTUSMS Did you also removed the filter from the ngRepeat

Comment: yes sir! I as reading into the error and it says a required dependency didnt resolve. Not sure if dataImagesWork has to be declared somewhere else or anything like that. I'm still trying to understand Angular infrastructure

Comment: In general it means that one of the modules you have loaded can't be loaded, try remove all of them except ngRoute and see if it's works

Comment: It didn't. I also changed to a different jquery version without luck. Do you think a more modern version of angular will do the trick? I guess I can try that...EDIT- nope, v1.50 didn't fix it either

Comment: I found the issue by the way, another script was conflicting. I didn't think it would since it was a sliding feature I no longer use. I removed all injections an dependencies for it so it shouldn't be conflicting. But I added it back from my backup and the ng-repeat works now. :shrugs:

Comment: Your filter removal did solve a 1 second flicker I had so that was cool. And for that, I'll check your answer. It did improve my code

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove 'uiGmapgoogle-maps' of the module dependecies
2. Links with data-binding, you must use use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref), replacing href
3. I recommend write your angular app following the [preparation guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#preparation) for angular 2. and Jhon Papa's angular style guide